# How not to lose the transparency of png when superimposed on another picture PHP?

Tags: php, gd

I have 2 pictures one will be as a background and the other should overlay it with a rounded corner. Png corners made transparent as i need. now when i want to impose on the other picture that transparent edges become black, i need that the transparent edges were not visible when both pictures merge.

here is the code :

```
<?php
$img1 = "image/image11.png";
$img2 = "image/test8.jpg";

$radius = 50;


$widthSize = 500; 
$heightSize = 500;
$opacityimgFilter = 100; 
$resizeFileName = "Resized";


$new_name2 = basename($img2);
$imgFilter = $img2;
$imageorig = basename($img2);
$dir = mb_strcut($img2 , 0 , strlen($img2)-strlen($imageorig));
$img = $dir.$imageorig;
$images = glob($img);
$im_php = imagecreatefromjpeg($img);
$im_php = imagescale($im_php, $widthSize, $heightSize);
$new_height = imagesy($im_php);

$img = $im_php; 
$image = $img;
imageCreateCorners($image , $radius , $resizeFileName , $img2  , $img1);
function imageCreateCorners($sourceImageFile, $radius , $last , $img2  , $img1) {

    $res = is_array($info = array(500,500));

    if ($res) {
        $w = $info[0];
        $h = $info[1];
        switch ('image/jpeg') {
        case 'image/jpeg': $src = $sourceImageFile;
            break;
        case 'image/gif': $src = $sourceImageFile;
            break;
        case 'image/png': $src = $sourceImageFile;
            break;
        default: 
            $res = false;
        }
    }

    if ($res) {

        $q = 10;
        $radius *= $q;

        do {
        $r = rand(0, 255);
        $g = rand(0, 255);
        $b = rand(0, 255);
        }
        while (imagecolorexact($src, $r, $g, $b) < 0);

        $nw = $w*$q;
        $nh = $h*$q;

        $img = imagecreatetruecolor($nw, $nh);
        $alphacolor = imagecolorallocatealpha($img, $r, $g, $b, 127);
        imagealphablending($img, false);
        imagesavealpha($img, true);
        imagefilledrectangle($img, 0, 0, $nw, $nh, $alphacolor);

        imagefill($img, 0, 0, $alphacolor);
        imagecopyresampled($img, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nw, $nh, $w, $h);

        imagearc($img, $radius-1, $radius-1, $radius*2, $radius*2, 180, 270, $alphacolor);
        imagefilltoborder($img, 0, 0, $alphacolor, $alphacolor);
        imagearc($img, $nw-$radius, $radius-1, $radius*2, $radius*2, 270, 0, $alphacolor);
        imagefilltoborder($img, $nw-1, 0, $alphacolor, $alphacolor);
        imagearc($img, $radius-1, $nh-$radius, $radius*2, $radius*2, 90, 180, $alphacolor);
        imagefilltoborder($img, 0, $nh-1, $alphacolor, $alphacolor);
        imagearc($img, $nw-$radius, $nh-$radius, $radius*2, $radius*2, 0, 90, $alphacolor);
        imagefilltoborder($img, $nw-1, $nh-1, $alphacolor, $alphacolor);
        imagealphablending($img, true);
        imagecolortransparent($img, $alphacolor);

        $dest = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
        imagealphablending($dest, false);
        imagesavealpha($dest, true);
        imagefilledrectangle($dest, 0, 0, $w, $h, $alphacolor);
        imagecopyresampled($dest, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $nw, $nh);

        $res = $dest;
        imagedestroy($src);
        imagedestroy($img);
        imagedestroy($dest);
    }
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($img1);
    $bg = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($image), imagesy($image));
    imagefill($bg, 0, 0, imagecolorallocate($bg, 255, 255, 255));
    imagealphablending($bg, TRUE);
    imagecopymerge($bg, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($image), imagesy($image) , 100);
    imagedestroy($image);
    $quality = 100; // 0 = worst / smaller file, 100 = better / bigger file 
    imagejpeg($bg, "output" . ".jpg", $quality);

    $image = $bg;

    $watermark = $res;
    list($watermark_width, $watermark_height) = array(500,500);
    $x = 0;
    $y = 0;
    imagecopymerge($image, $watermark, $x, $y, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height, 100);
    imagecopy($image, $watermark, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($watermark), imagesy($watermark));
    $nameRes = basename($img2 , "jpg");

    imagepng($image, $last."/".$nameRes."-ee."."png");
    imagedestroy($res);

    $nameRes = basename($img2 , "jpg");
    imagepng($res, $last."/".$nameRes."png");
    imagedestroy($res);
    ob_clean();
    // Вывод изображения на браузер
    $im22 = imagecreatefrompng( $last."/".$nameRes."png");
    header('Content-type: image/png');  
    imagepng($im22);
    imagedestroy($im22);
}

?>
```

Png corners made transparent as i need. now when i want to impose on the other picture that transparent edges become black, i need that the transparent edges were not visible when both pictures merge.